# File.exists() Method always returns true even when the file doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, android-file

Im trying to curb duplicate downloads by checking if the file a user is about to download already exists before I proceed to downloading it.
Im using the method File.exists() to check for this condition but it seems to be always returning true.
Below is my code:

```
            File destination = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/" + playlistTitle + "/" + image.getImgTitle() + ".jpg");
            if (!destination.exists()) {
                downloadId = downloadImage(image.getImgURL(), image.getImgTitle(), playlistTitle);
                downloadIds.add(downloadId);
            }
```

If I go directly to that file path before its created, it seems to be empty, but the code above returns true regardless.

Comment: If you create a new file just before checking if it exist , it will always exist right ?

Comment: Who is creating a new file?

Answer (score 1):

You can check few things here

first as expected we are getting the permission to read and write the storage media.

and you try also using below method for checking if a file can be read or not

```
if (!file.canRead()) {
    return false;
}
```

if two above doesn't work then use this.

```
if (!file.isFile()) {
     //file doesn't exist    
    }else{
    //file exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/" + playlistTitle
```

That can only lead to a path that is not possible.

You should use instead

```
new File( Environment.getExternalPublicDirectory( 
      Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),......
```

Comment: I have tried this, using getExternalStoragePublicDirectory, it still doesnt work, always returns true

Comment: Pretty unclear where you have problems. If the file exists than File.exists() will return true.

Comment: Ok so this is what Im facing, I want to download a file but before downloading it I want to first check if it was downloaded before using File.exists(), if this returns false then Ill go ahead and download it, else if this returns true, Ill let the user know that the file exists and open it. Problem is that whether the file exists or not it always returns false

Comment: `new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/" + playlistTitle...` That is still wrong code. Update your post with the right code please.